# pip install virtual env wrapper - win shows error:

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install Django in my windows 7 machine, as a prerequisite, I am installing `virtualenvwrapper`:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

But it throws the following error:

```
Error [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect while executing command 
python setup.py egg_info
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] The paramet
er is incorrect
```

[**NOTE**]:

- Python version : Python 3.7.0b4
- pip version: pip 10.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [**pyenv**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv):

**Step 1:**
install `virtualenv` using `pip`

```
pip install virtualenv
```

**Step 2**
In a folder, open `cmd` and run:

```
python -m venv virtualenvname
```

eg:
    python -m venv india

**Step 3:** Activate your Virtual environment by:

```
india\Scripts\activate
```

**Note:** `S` of `sripts` has to be in caps

Now you must see `india` before location in your cmd. If yes then your virtual env has been activated.

Something Like this:

```
(india) D:\dev\python\django\
```

Comment: I have succesffully installed install virtualenv and django but could not execute django-admin.py startproject projname

Comment: @vSugumar Sir, Its `django-admin startproject projname`. Remove the `.py` from `admin`.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 -m venv yourprojectname
```

Are you trying my command. I got the error like you did with this command I got the problem

but, you can apply the following commands

```
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
py -m virtualenv env
```

OR

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv

python3 -m virtualenv env
```