# Why VirtualENV as django run well without venv?

Tags: python, django, pipenv, python-venv, pyenv

I am trying to learn Django since long but I always run the server without any venv, yet it runs well.

My Question is: Why people install venv to run their project?

What is the benefit of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51472200/5901723