# Pip install and Easy install Django and VirtualEnv not working

Tags: python, django, web, pip

I am trying to install virtualenv and django and i keep getting  errors.I tried using the whql file of virtualenv but still, no solution.My windows firewall is also turned off.This is the error message for virtualenv,The same thing happens when i try installing flask also.

```
C:\Windows\system32>easy_install virtualenv
Searching for virtualenv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: [WinError 10061] N
o connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Som
e packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'virtualenv' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [WinError 10061] No connectio
n could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some packages
may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for virtualenv
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('virtualenv')

C:\Windows\system32>pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DD70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/virt
ualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DED0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/virt
ualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DDD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/virt
ualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DB30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/virt
ualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DC90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/virt
ualenv/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv                                       (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

This is the error message for Django.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install django
Collecting django
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DE90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/djan
go/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DE30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/djan
go/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DD50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/djan
go/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DDB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/djan
go/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip.
_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0298DC10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/djan
go/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions:
 )
No matching distribution found for django

C:\Windows\system32>easy_install django
Searching for django
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: [WinError 10061] No co
nnection could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some pa
ckages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'django' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [WinError 10061] No connectio
n could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some packages
may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for django
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('django')

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Check these solutions if it works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449839/6759844
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47460697/6759844

The first link is for fixing what seems to be a proxy problem within your Windows machine. The second one is if all else fails, download the wheel package and install via pip

Comment: Hi @Dalisey, i suggest you to have a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319773/5901723

Comment: Thank you very much @bdbd the first thread worked perfectly,I had to untick use proxy for LAN after this the pip command worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably tackle this with pip. I would do the following:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then next in your directory you choose to set up your virtual environment. Then nexxt name your virtual enviornment:

```
virtualenv pymote_env
```

Then after we do that we can call the virtual enviornment as so:
 pymote_env\Scripts\activate(pymote_env)

Then when the virtual environment call the pip command to verify it works

```
pip
```

Then after install django:

```
pip install django
```

Hopefully this is what your looking for. H

Comment: Thank you but I can't seem to get the first command running due to the error I keep getting.

Comment: What is the error do you have pip installed on your computer? If you don't have pip then follow the instructions it shouldn't take you long https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: I have pip installed properly and easy install also

Comment: Thanks you also your command was a guide to installing django.

Comment: glad I helped a little :)