# installed django-redis in python virtualenv, redis-cli command not found

Tags: django, redis-cli, django-redis

I just install `django-redit` using `pip` in my python virtualenv,but when I enter command  `redis-cli`, it shows me **`redis-cli command not found`.**

I'm pretty much sure redis-cli has been installed sucessfully.
need your help
thx in advance

Comment: you can freeze the packages installed in your `virtualenv` to confirm if its installed. try `pip freeze`. If not then you can follow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319773/5901723

Comment: please see my new post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Redis client/server (https://redis.io/). Depending on you OS you maybe can install this directly by OS repository.

Comment: sames like whatever the package has been installed in virtualenv, still has a bash:command not found.

Comment: when i'm going to try wget http://xxxxxx, shows me command not found. but im pretty sure  wget has been installed successfully into my virtual env by using pip install. confused

Comment: On what OS are you? wget is installed on most Linux distro's, but not on Windows and MAC. About the `pip install redis` with that you have installed is a lib to interact with a Redis. But you need to have the Redis installed somewhere.

Comment: thats my problem i think. my OS is MAC. one more question here: just download and install Redis anywhere on my mac or still need to do some configuration？

Comment: Never worked on MAC so couldn't tell you much, maybe take a look here (https://1upnote.me/post/2018/06/install-config-redis-on-mac-homebrew/). Looks like `brew install redis` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this commands:

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install django
pip install redis
```

Comment: @Chase.yang try this `pip install redis-cli-cluster`

Comment: sames like whatever the package has been installed in virtualenv, still has a bash:command not found.

Comment: try to install globally

Answer (score 0):

##### Install REDIS with brew (for django)

- `brew install redis`
- `brew list`
- if you want run redis when you start project: `shell ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`
- start redis with brew : `brew services start redis`
- start redis with config :  `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`
- `brew services stop redis`
- `redis config location : /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`
- `redis detail : brew info redis`
- `redis test : redis-cli ping`
- `pipenv install django-redis-cache`
- `brew uninstall redis`